# Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int return salary

Tags: arrays, performance, oop

I have tried many methods but I can't fix this Problem.
My code is

```
public class Employee extends Person{
  float salary;
  int yearOfStarted;
  String nationalInsuranceNumber;

  float getSalary(){
    return (float)salary;
  }

  void setSalary(float salary){
    salary = this.salary;
  }
}
```

the Error comes at getSalary method whenever It compiles.

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int return salary;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Seemingly there is nothing wrong with your code. It would be helpful if you tell us which language are you using for this code sample.

Answer (score -1):

As I can see there was a blank at the end of `return (float)salary ;` in your original code.

```
float getSalary(){
  return (float)salary;
}
```

Comment: That is completely irrelevant.  The presence or absence of a space before the semicolon *only* affects readability.