# Integer to byte does not compile

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte

I have two programs which are almost identical. The first compiles, the second not. Why?

I am assigning an `int` variable to a `byte` variable.

This one compiles:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int x = 127; // directly initialized

        byte b;
        b = x;

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

This one does not compile:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int x;
        x = 127; // assigned later

        byte b;
        b = x;

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

The compiler says *incompatible types* at `b = x;`. But shouldn't the same apply to the first version as well?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the error message you get.

Comment: Isn’t compiled with what error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "possible lossy conversion" mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Progman That answers don't clear my problem

Comment: Next time, please show the full error message you get, with the line information etc.

Comment: @Progman Not a duplicate. I agree though that the initial version of the question was not formulated that clearly. But now it is pretty clear what OP is asking at what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 9):

This one is obscure.  Really obscure.

The first version works because the JLS says in section [§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) that you can assign an `int` value to a `byte` variable if the value is the result of a *constant expression* AND the int value is in the range -128 to +127.   A *constant variable* is a *constant expression*, and `final int x = 127;` declares a *constant variable*.

The second version doesn't work because `final int x;` doesn't declare a *constant variable*. The JLS says the following in section [§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String **that is initialized with a constant expression** (§15.28).

In the second version, the final variable has a blank initializer and is then assigned later.  The upshot is that the rule in §5.2 that allows narrowing of primitive constants in an assignment is not allowed.

---

Why couldn't `final int x;` be treated as a compile time constant?

Consider this:

```
    final int x;
    if (something) {
        x = 127;
    } else {
        x = 1023;
    }
    byte b = x;
```

Should the initialization of `b` be allowed, or will it be a "lossy" conversion?  It depends on the value of `something`.

Hypothetically, a compiler could decide in some variants of the example above that all possible values of `x` would be OK, but the added complexity in the compiler *and the language specification* is not justifiable.