# What does this error mean? "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int" Am I doing something wrong with the syntax?

Tags: java

This is a java program to calculate [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem):
Fermat’s Last Theorem says that there are no integers   a ,   b , and   c  such that

> a<sup>n</sup>+b<sup>n</sup>=c<sup>n</sup>

except when   n≤2 .

Write a program named Fermat.java that inputs four integers (a, b, c, and n) and checks to see if Fermat’s theorem holds.
If   *n*  is greater than 2 and    a<sup>n</sup>+b<sup>n</sup>=c<sup>n</sup>  , the program should display

“Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!”

Otherwise the program should display

“No, that doesn’t work.”

Tried making the parameters in `checkFermat` from `int` to `double` with no success.

---

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fermat{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    checkFermat(1,2,4,1);
  }

  public static void checkFermat(int a,int b,int c,int n){
    int result = ((Math.pow (a,n))+(Math.pow(b,n)));
    if ((((Math.pow(a, n)) + (Math.pow(b, n))) == (Math.pow(c, n))) && ((n != 2))) {
      System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
      
    }else{
      System.out.println("No, that doesn't work.");
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is the error:

```
code/Fermat.java:11: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    int result = ((Math.pow (a,n))+(Math.pow(b,n)));
                                  ^
1 error
```

Comment: A "Lossy Conversion" means that data loss may occur.  When converting from a `double` to an `int`, the fractional part of the number is discarded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "possible lossy conversion" mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The method you use lies within `java.lang.Math` which goes as `public static double pow(double, double)`. It expects both the base and exponent to be of the type `double`. Which works fine in this case (of passing integers) due to implicit type converging form `int` → `double`, as double has higher hierarchy, more number of bytes, greater precision and hence can store larger range of numbers.

[image: Hierarchy of data types]

Things become quite tricky when you reverse the operation. Which in this can can be noticed.

```
code/Fermat.java:11: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    int result = ((Math.pow (a,n))+(Math.pow(b,n)));
                                  ^
1 error
```

Here, the type needs to be converted from `double` → `int` as the return type of `Math.pow(double, double)` is of type `double`. The type should be either `double` or any other data type which will be more in hierarchy position than `double`. Which is not, the storing value is `int` which is way less than `double` and can cause loss of data, in terms of accuracy. Maybe returning value is a floating value which is not possible when it comes to integer numbers but range issue, some squaring of numbers may take a very large value incapable of storing within `int`, hence the error message you see is to inform you that the types is inappropriate and might be a cause for loss in precision.

**How to overcome this ?** 
*1. Either use an appropriate data type* 
(Recommended) Use the data type as expected for holding the returned data.
For example: `double result = ((Math.pow (a,n))+(Math.pow(b,n)));`

*2. Explicit type casting* 
Explicitly say the compiler to cast down the data from `double` → `int` caring less about the data. 
For example: `int result = (int)((Math.pow (a,n))+(Math.pow(b,n)));`