# How do I fix this error,[Beginner] (highlighted in bold and italic)

Tags: java

There is an error that shows up
Error: possible lossy convertion from double to int

```
    double[] MyArr = {0,1,2,3};
    double sum = 0;
    for (double a=0; a< MyArr.length; a++){

        ***sum += MyArr[a];***
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: an index variable should always be of type `int`. Why do you use a `double`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "possible lossy conversion" mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `for (int a = 0; a < MyArr.length; a++)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `int` instead of `double` because `index` should always be `int`.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
           int[] MyArr = {0,1,2,3};
            int sum = 0;
    for (int a=0; a< MyArr.length; a++){

        sum += MyArr[a];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
double[] MyArr = {0,1,2,3};
double sum = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < MyArr.length ; ++a){

    sum = sum + MyArr[a];
    
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

For reaching any index from a list, you have to use an integer.