# getting error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float for type promotion code

Tags: java, type-promotion

i didnt understand the error when executing below code.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        byte b=2;
        short s=7;
        int i=11002;
        char c = 's';
        float f = 9.987;
        double d = .879;
        int res = (f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s);
        System.out.println("(f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s)");
        System.out.println("result = "+res);
    }
}
```

errors i get:

Main.java:7: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
float f = 9.987;
^
Main.java:9: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
int res = (f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s);
^
2 errors

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be getting these errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "possible lossy conversion" mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Sweeper i have no idea pls explain

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are beginner in java . So the mistake you are making is typecasting . You can not assign double value to a float type .

Try this code

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        byte b=2;
        short s=7;
        int i=11002;
        char c = 's';
        float f = 9.987f;
        double d = .879;
        int res = (int) ((f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s));
        System.out.println("(f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s)");
        System.out.println("result = "+res);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to face this problem again in future learn about type casting (automatic conversion and explicit conversion).

Answer (score 0):

The result of an operation between different data types will always be the largest type (here double).
If you want to keep the result as an int : look into casting values.

It should look like this : `int res = (int) ((f*b) + (i/c) - (d*s))`

Otherwise, make the result a double.

Also, floats in java need to have f at the end : `float f = 9.987f;`