# (Java) incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

Tags: java

here's my code. i wanted to display the name of the month instead of number. but there's an error in my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class myIDCard{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long myID;
        long a,b,c,a1,a2,a3;
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your Name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your IC number without dash: ");
        myID = in.nextLong();
        in.nextLine();
        
        a = myID/1000000;
        b = myID/10000%100;
        c = myID%10000;
        a1 = a%100;
        a2 = a/100%100;
        a3 = a/10000;
        String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mac", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jly", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dis"};
        String month = months[a2 - 1];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your name : " + name);
        System.out.println("Your IC number : " + a + "-" + b + "-" + c);
        System.out.println("Your Birth date : " + a1 + "/" + month + "/" + a3);
        
        if (c % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("Your Gender is : Female");
        else
            System.out.println("Your Gender is : Male");
    }
}
```

it said that "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int".
the error in my code was:-

```
String month = months[a2 - 1];
```

Comment: Cast it to `int`.

Comment: (See *"Possible lossy conversion" when subscripting."* in the [duplink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it).)

Comment: Neither of the answers to this question really explained *why* this is a lossy conversion.  The reason is that array subscripts in Java are converted to `int` values.  Converting a `long` expression to an `int` is lossy.

Answer (score 2):

A `long` uses more bits than an `int`, so it can hold larger numbers than an `int`. It has more digits so to speak. Just like you can express a larger number with 3 digits (0 to 999) than 2 digits (0 to 99), this is true for `long` compared to `int` except the digits are in base 2 instead of base 10. The digits are called bits.

A common source of programmer error is using a `long` where an `int` is requested. In some languages, the compiler will generate code that implicitly transforms the `long` into an `int`. If you're lucky, you might get a compiler warning. If you're luckier, the value in the `long` will fit in the `int`, so the logic of your program remains correct. If you're unlucky, you truncate some of the digits in your `long`, and you have a tough bug to find and fix.

Java has design goals to simplify things and prevent programmer error. The specification mandates that an automatic transformation cannot take place, turning a `long` into an `int`. Instead, the specification mandates that a compiler error happen.

If you're extra sure that the value in your `long` fits in your `int`, you can manually cast it from a `long` to an `int` like so: `someInteger = (int) someLong;`. In your case, it might look like `String month = months[(int)a2 - 1];`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to `int`

```java
String month = months[(int)a2 - 1];
```